# Some theoretical question on Euler product

Tags: dirichlet-series, euler-product

It is very rare that the Euler product
\[
\lim_{X \to \infty}\prod_{p \leq X}(1 + a(p)p^{-s})
\]
conditionally converges for $\sigma > A$ with some $0 < A \leq 1$
when $|a(n)| = 1$.

Suppose that this is the case (and thus a "theoretical" question). Then has there been any general theory established already? I guess there should be, but google search (my only search tool) doesn't give me any.

Especially, I would like to know if the convergence of 
\[
\lim_{X \to \infty}\prod_{p \leq X}(1 + a(p)p^{-s}) \quad \sigma > A
\]
implies that of
\[
\sum_{n} \frac{a(n)|\mu(n)|}{n^{s}} \quad \sigma > A.
\]
For simplicity, I assumed $a(n)$ to be multiplicative.

The expansion of the finite product
\[
\prod_{p \leq X}(1 + a(p)p^{-s}) = \sum_{p|n \Rightarrow p \leq X}\frac{a(n)|\mu(n)|}{n^{s}}
\]
is just "one way to sum", and I can't say it's a Dirichlet series without additional arguments I guess.